# How to remove decimal places from SQL 2005 query result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SQL version = 2005.
```

The following query produces the result 2.000000. I would like it to show just 2.

How do i remove decimal places from the result ?

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM([Total Order (mins)])/60, 0) as [Total Cutting Time (Hours) Saw 50] FROM [IT_REPORTS].[dbo].[cutting_data] WHERE [AssignedCuttingDate] = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) and [Saw No] = '50'
```

Comment: select Convert(int, 2.000000)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you type out exactly how I would do it using the query above?

Comment: Problem here is if you convert it to INT, it will give you whole number ... Convert(int, SUM([Total Order (mins)])/60) as [Total Cutting Time (Hours) Saw 50]  ... but when you run it next time and have some numbers in decimal places it will not be shown ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `round()` is that the *value* changes, but not necessarily the *type*.  So, you might get a bunch of trailing zeros, as you have noticed.

My advice is to convert to a decimal (or integer):

```
SELECT CAST(SUM([Total Order (mins)])/60 as DECIMAL(10, 0)) as [Total Cutting Time (Hours) Saw 50]
FROM [IT_REPORTS].[dbo].[cutting_data]
WHERE [AssignedCuttingDate] = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0) AND
      [Saw No] = '50';
```

You can also use `str()` to convert to a string.